# Getting Module Not found error: importlib.resources in windows 7 python 3.7version

Tags: pip, runtime-error, modulenotfounderror, python-importlib

Getting Module Not found Error:No Module named 'importlib.resources'

Module not found error in windows 7 python version 3.7
I'm trying to run one picture in terminal using python programming after I successfully completed code It shows error like there is no module named 'importlib.resources'

After all I verify whether I correctly installed pip  and pip3 versions in command prompt it also starts showing no module named 'importlib.resources'

I'm in search to solve this issue for an couple of hours  No use and simply got an idea to make query in stack over flow.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: Tried something from https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=No+Module+named+%22importlib.resources%22 ?